# Invalid connection string when connecting to SQL Server Express

Tags: sql-server, system.data

I tried every single variation that I could find on the internet. Everything. And still every time I get the very same exception:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 25 - Connection string is not valid)'

With this weird inner exception:

> SocketException: The operation completed successfully

When I specify the port directly, then I end up with this wonderful exception:

> An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions

No matter what, it doesn't work. Moreover I'd like to have MS SQL Management Studio open while testing (that was the only process which could block the port).

So why does it not work? Management Studio can connect with `IP\InstanceName` without a problem. Why is the `System.Data.Sql.SqlConnection` class incapable of doing so?

```
        SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
        builder.DataSource = "tcp:***.***.***.***\\SQLEXPRESS";
        builder.InitialCatalog = "MyDB";
        builder.Password = "MyPass";
        builder.UserID = "ID";
        builder.IntegratedSecurity = false;
        _connection = new SqlConnection(builder.ToString());
```

FYI: I am using the ConnectionStringBuilder, so there shouldn't be any issue. Server name, instance name, SQL user and password are valid and I did explicitly set `Integrated Security = False`.

Comment: pls share your connection string

Comment: Can you share your connection string ?

Comment: Here you go. Added the code.

Comment: here is something you can try. Create a `.TXT`file anywhere on your computer and rename its extension to `.UDL` Now doubleclick on that file, you will get the ADO window to build a connectionstring with a `test connection`button. Using this window sometimes provides other/better error messages and if you get this connection to work, than you can open the `UDL`file in notepath where you will see a complete connectionstring you can use

Comment: It still doesn't work. I tried that string already. SqlException in C# whereas the ADO window does connect successfully...

Comment: Ah ... okay I noticed that it's a different error now, though: `"A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)"`

Comment: So you are saying that the ADO Window can connect without problem, and when you copy the exact connectionstring from this file into your .net project it does not works ?

Comment: Yes. Am currently trying to check out the source code but it's not that easy to build corefx. My only guess is that it's an corefx-issue...

Comment: or there might be something in the firewall on your machine refusing the sql server port for your app or for all dotnet apps, just a guess

Comment: Already tried disabling the firewall. Did not work either...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was (which was not really clear) that UWP requires a capabilitiy in order to run that code. I read somewhere that you would need *Enterprise Authentication* which was not the one. Since my program and server are in a closed, private network I enabled *Private Networks (Client & Server)*.

The one you would need is *Internet (Client & Server)*. Sadly the exceptions don't hint to that and the fact that SqlClient on UWP requires this to work is nearly nowhere mentioned or not stressed enough so you wouldn't overlook it.

Solution found in this [.Net Standard issue](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/578).

Comment: This issue has been driving me nuts for days, and this solution was the first thing that actually allowed me to connect to the database. I still get an error, but at least I am connecting to it... progress! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

First of all try to connect to this database using SQL Server Management Studio. 
If you get the same error, it means that there is a problem with the server not (or not only) with your connection string. 
Here is some of possibilities :

1- Remove 'tcp:' from this part:   builder.DataSource = "tcp:***.***.***.***\SQLEXPRESS";

2- On the server the SQL Server services (SQL Server or SQL Server browser) are stopped.
To activate go Services and start stopped services.

3- May be the server doesn't accept remote connections:
In this case on the server open SQL Server Configuration Manager

[image]

And activate tcp ip.

You should restart SQL Server service after this operation.

Tell me if it works for you.

Comment: As I said, I can connect with Management Studio using `IP\Instance`. It's definetly an issue on .Net side. The ports are set to allow in the server's firewall. For instance: We connect to the server in another program via Entity Framework. There it does work fine. Furthermore: I am developing a UWP app on .Net Standard 2.0.

Comment: Did you try to remove 'tcp:' from this part ?  builder.DataSource = "tcp:***.***.***.***\\SQLEXPRESS";

Comment: Yes. I tried everything. IP-Instance, IP-Port, Computername-Instance, ... nothing works.

Comment: Can you try like this  :  builder.DataSource = @"***.***.***.***\SQLEXPRESS";